# Bug with page speed insights for leverage browser caching

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

The google page speed tool doesn’t recognize the + x months in wordpress htaccess files from popular caching plugins.

The base is from start day + 2 months. Page speed only recognizes it as one month.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fuooutlands.com

Example
"access plus 2 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 2 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png

Answer (score 2):

It isn't Google PSI, you haven't configured something correctly.

I downloaded one image and checked the headers, they are set at 30 days expiry.

```
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=86400; v="43,39"
cache-control: max-age=2592000
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: image/webp
date: Wed, 13 Nov 2019 14:42:41 GMT
**expires: Fri, 13 Dec 2019 14:42:34 GMT**
last-modified: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 01:26:57 GMT
server: nginx
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=300
vary: Accept,Accept-Encoding
x-proxy-cache: HIT
```

### Edit

You are using `Nginx` webserver - does that not render `.htaccess` useless?